# SSE Laravel : EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection

Tags: laravel, server-sent-events

In local development systems I did not get any such errors but while deploying in live production server I am getting following errors.

**EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.**

I am using laravel. I have set headers in controller function as following.
I found many people are having same issues in different framworks but could not found working solution for me.

Can anyone have solution or suggestion to this? Thanks in advance.

Following is javascript SSE call.

```
<script>
if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined"){
    var source = new EventSource("/sse");
    source.addEventListener("response", function(event) {
         document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "<p>RESPONSE DATA</p><p>" + event.data + "</p>";
    });
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events.";
}
```

Following is Laravel Controller function. I have also tried setting headers in **public function __construct(){}** and also tried setting in **public function index(){}** That didnot helped either.

```
public function sse($userid,Request $request){
    header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

    $SERVER = env('SERVER','');
    $url    = $SERVER.'/stream';
    $user   = Auth::user();
    $gwuser = $user->gwuser;
    $gwpass = $user->gwpass;


    ini_set('output_buffering', 'off');
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression',false);
    ini_set('implicit_flush',true);

    while (@ob_end_flush()){
    ob_implicit_flush(true);

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $gwuser . ':' . $gwpass);

        $error  = 0;

        //$result = curl_exec($ch);
        //This while loop is only for server timeout after 5 minutes
        while(true){
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
        }


    }

}
```

I have also tried using Middleware to set headers for selected route call and assign middleware to that route. That didnot helped.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;

class setHeader
{
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);
    $response->header('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
    $response->header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    return $response;

}

}
```

Comment: Could you get a solution to this?